# python flask socketio not calling a custom event from JS file

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, flask-socketio

I have this `JS` code from where I first establish a connection to `flask` app  using `socketio`:

I am placing a microphone button on my `html` page and on click it triggers the code in `JS` to connect to `python` `flask` app.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="static/chat/js/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="require.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="speech.css">
</head>
<body>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <nav class="navbar-left" height="100" style="background-color: #092A66 !important;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" padding-top=0 padding-bottom=0 href="#">
        <img src="image.jpg"  height="100" alt="">
      </a>
    </nav>
 <br><br>
 <div class="container">
                <div id="chat" class="jumbotron" style="height:600px;background-color:white">
                    <div id="conversations" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:500px;overflow:auto; ">
                          <div class="arrow"></div>
                              <ul class="CL">
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="compose-message">
                        <label for="new-input-message">{{gettext('Message')}}</label>
                        <input type="text" id="new-input-message" class="speech-input" aria-describedby="new-input-message-help-block" name="eng-input" lang = "en" disabled="false">

                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
<script src="static/speech-in.js"></script>   
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function()
{
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
// OTHER IMPORTANT CODE FOR FURTHER PROCESSING
 .
 . 
 .
});
</script>
```

**speech-in.js:**

```
/*global webkitSpeechRecognition */


(function() {
    'use strict';

    // check for support (webkit only)
//  if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) return;

    var talkMsg = 'Speak now';
    // seconds to wait for more input after last
    var defaultPatienceThreshold = 6;

    function capitalize(str) {
        return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    }
    console.log('Check 1');
    var inputEls = document.getElementsByClassName('speech-input');

    [].forEach.call(inputEls, function(inputEl) {
        var patience = parseInt(inputEl.dataset.patience, 10) || defaultPatienceThreshold;
        var micBtn, micIcon, holderIcon, newWrapper;
        var shouldCapitalize = true;

        // gather inputEl data
        var nextNode = inputEl.nextSibling;
        var parent = inputEl.parentNode;
        var inputRightBorder = parseInt(getComputedStyle(inputEl).borderRightWidth, 10);
        var buttonSize = 0.8 * (inputEl.dataset.buttonsize || inputEl.offsetHeight);

        // default max size for textareas
        if (!inputEl.dataset.buttonsize && inputEl.tagName === 'TEXTAREA' && buttonSize > 26) {
            buttonSize = 26;
        }

        // create wrapper if not present
        var wrapper = inputEl.parentNode;
        if (!wrapper.classList.contains('si-wrapper')) {
            wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.classList.add('si-wrapper');
            wrapper.appendChild(parent.removeChild(inputEl));
            newWrapper = true;
        }
        console.log('Check 2');
        // create mic button if not present
        micBtn = wrapper.querySelector('.si-btn');
        if (!micBtn) {
            micBtn = document.createElement('button');
            micBtn.type = 'button';
            micBtn.classList.add('si-btn');
            micBtn.textContent = 'speech input';
            micIcon = document.createElement('span');
            holderIcon = document.createElement('span');
            micIcon.classList.add('si-mic');
            holderIcon.classList.add('si-holder');
            micBtn.appendChild(micIcon);
            micBtn.appendChild(holderIcon);
            wrapper.appendChild(micBtn);

            // size and position mic and input
            micBtn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            micBtn.style.top = 0.125 * buttonSize + 'px';
            micBtn.style.height = micBtn.style.width = buttonSize + 'px';
            inputEl.style.paddingRight = buttonSize - inputRightBorder + 'px';
        }

        // append wrapper where input was
        if (newWrapper) parent.insertBefore(wrapper, nextNode);

        // setup recognition

        function initializeRecorder(strean){
           audio_context = new AudioContext;
           sampleRate = audio_context.sampleRate;
           var audioInput = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

           console.log("Created media stream.");

           var bufferSize = 4096;
           // record only 1 channel
           var recorder = audio_context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
           // specify the processing function
           recorder.onaudioprocess = recorderProcess;
           // connect stream to our recorder
           audioInput.connect(recorder);
           // connect our recorder to the previous destination
           recorder.connect(audio_context.destination);
        }
        micBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

            console.log('Check 3')
            socket.on('connect', function() {

            console.log('Check 4')
            // subscribe to events here - THIS DOES NOT GET CALLED
            socket.on('speech', function (data) {

                console.log('Check 5') // THIS DOES NOT APPEAR ON CONSOLE
                 socket.send("sample rate:" + sampleRate);
                 navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}, initializeRecorder, function(e) {
                            console.log('No live audio input: ' + e);
                        });
                 console.log('Check 6') // THIS DOES NOT APPEAR ON CONSOLE
                console.log('Event received data:' + JSON.stringify(data));
                });
            });
        }, false);
        console.log('Check 7');


    });
    console.log('Check 8');
})();
```

**flask-app.py:**

```
import sys
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,redirect, session, Markup, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send,emit
from flask_babel import Babel
import configparser
from speech_api_text import main


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abccefg'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
babel = Babel(app)

@socketio.on('speech')
def speech_api():

   try:
       # I DO NOT SEE THIS PRINT IN MY CONSOLE
       print('SPEECH METHOD GOT CALLED')
       # THis doesnt work
       #emit(main())
       emit('Hello and Hi')
   except Exception as e:
       print('Exception in SPEEECH API is - '+str(e))

@socketio.on('connect')
def handleConnect():

    try:
        msg = 'Hello!'
        print(msg)
        emit('message', msg)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception is - ',str(e))
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        socketio.run(app)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

As you can see I am connecting to `flask` app in the `JS` code and I can see the `console.log('check 3')` and `console.log('Check 4')` coming on my console when I click the microphone button. But nothing happens and I do not see `console.log('Check 5')` and `console.log('Check 6')` on the console and neither the `print` statement under my `flask-app.py` code. It seems the custom event `speech` is not getting called. What is the mistake I am making here?

Comment: There are no events coming from the server in the topic `speech`

Comment: @edkeveked i\I have tried using emit('Hello and Hi') from withing `speech` event of my flask app but still same. I do not see any console or print statements coming in. You can see updated code in my `flask-app.py` code above

Answer (score 1):

You are not emitting anything in the topic `speech` from the server. That is why the part of your code that is listening to `speech` event is not executed.

Consider emitting something from the server upon user connection `emit('speech', msg)`

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def handleConnect():

    try:
        msg = 'Hello!'
        print(msg)
        emit('speech', msg)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception is - ',str(e))
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        socketio.run(app)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

The `print` statement in the function `speech_api`is not executed because the function itself is not executed. `speech_api` can be considered as a listener to event sent to the server with the topic `speech`. The function will be executed only if in your client (js code) you are emitting with the topic `speech` like this `socket.emit('speech', message)`.

Comment: the connect part is working and I can see the statement from connect. But then I call `speech` and I am emitting a message from my `speech` function - `emit(main())` I am calling a function from within `emit()`.

Comment: i have tried using `emit('Hello and Hi')` from withing `speech` event of my flask app but still same. I do not see any console or print statements coming in

Comment: You have to emit with the right topic: here the correct topic should be `speech` that your client is listening to. `emit('Hello and Hi')` will no give you the desired output, because your client is not listening to `Hello and Hi`. Also `speech_api()` is not executed because for that, you have to emit from your client with the topic `speech`

Comment: so in my `connect` event method pf flask python code I should do `emit(`speech`,msg)` to call the `speech` event method?

Comment: Yes, you should call it. `emit('speech',msg)` (note that it is the string `'speech'`)

Comment: and to call a custom event, like `speech`, do I need to call it from `connect` event only? Can't I call the custom event directly from my JS code? The reason I am asking this is because I use `connect` event for other purpose also(as you can see I am calling `message` event from my `connect` event method currently.)

Comment: If you want to listen to an event with the Js code (`socket.on('speech')`, you need to emit from the server (`emit('speech')`. If you want to listen from the server (`@socketio.on('speech')`), you have to emit from the client (`socket.emit('speech)`) . You can do only one direction or both depending on your use case